# Angular ng-class (between 2 parameters)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class

How can I tell angular that angular adds my css class when the number is bigger then 14 and smaller then 20.

I got now something like this.

```
ng-class="{ day_yellow: weatherList.temp.max >= 15,  }">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple && condition :

```
ng-class="{ day_yellow: weatherList.temp.max >= 15 && weatherList.temp.max < 20  }">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most general solution:

```
ng-class="{true: 'day_yellow', false: 'some_other_class'}[weatherList.temp.max < 20 && weatherList.temp.max > 14]
```

If you need the CSS class only if the condition is true, you can use this:

```
ng-class="{'day_yellow': weatherList.temp.max < 20 && weatherList.temp.max > 14}
```

The other way is to place the condition into your controller and then use in HTML only the variable:

Controller

```
$scope.condition = weatherList.temp.max < 20 && weatherList.temp.max > 14;
```

HTML

```
ng-class="{'day_yellow': condition}
```